# How do I override the email field when resetting passwords?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to reset a password using Laravel built-in function. I know that it's possible to define a specfic password resetter using this:

```
public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('name');
}
```

But I would like to know if there's any way to do the same thing with the email field because my field has a different name and I get an SQL error.

Answer (score 2):

The trait `CanResetPassoword`, used by Laravel's `Authenticatable` class extended by the default `User` model, defines the method `getEmailForPasswordReset()`.

Assuming that you want to override that field for the `User` model, you can override it to return the proper value:

```php
/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    // Return the correct field value here
    return $this->email;
}
```